# Rails: setting attribute the right way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a DB attribute in my `Plan` model

`t.integer  "adult_only",         :default => 1`

Now I want to set the value of `adult_only = 0` if `user.intern?` What will be the rails way to do it? Should I do this in the `Plans controller` or the `view` or somewhere else?

EDIT

Now my scenario is that when I am creating a new Plan I want to set the adult_only value based on the check `user.intern?`, the first thing that comes to my mind is to do it in the `new` action of the `PlansController`, suggestions?

The relationships are as follows:

`User has_many Proposals` and `Proposals has_many Plans`

Comment: How does a plan relate to a user?

Comment: You can do this in model but let us know the models you have ..?

Comment: It means you are required that the adult only have 0 value by default on the place of 1, Am i right ?

Comment: No the default needs to be 1, it should be 0 only if the user.intern? is true

Comment: @RyanBigg User has_many Proposals and Proposals has_many Plans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@androidharry If you want it to display in the view and give option to user to change it before saving in DB(i.e. before reaching in Model), then you should set it in controller in new action.

```
def new
  @plan = Plan.new(adult_only: (user.intern? ? 0 : 1))
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to set it using an Active Record callback

this is code that is run either before or after an action that changes the model.

In this case - you want to do it before you create a new plan (ie just before it saves a new one)

The code itself is really straightforward.

in plan.rb:

```
before_create :set_adult_only

def set_adult_only
  return if defined?(self.adult_only)
  self.adult_only = 0 if user.intern?
end
```

Comment: I want to show this as a checkbox on the new view. A controller after_filter sounds good?

Comment: @Andoirdharry - no, setting a checkbox will be independent of the model. You'll be best adding a condition to your `before_create` callback to check if `adult_only` is set

Comment: The initial rendering value of the checkbox needs to be set, after that the user can uncheck/check it

Comment: @androidharry - this is something related to the data... therefore it should go in the model. Controllers are for directing page-flow only. You should not put business-logic in your controller. You should especially not put business logic that updates the data on your models.

Comment: If you want to put an initial value on your checkbox... you could just set a default for the column in the database?